# Getting Filename from URI while selecting an image in cordova

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am new to cordova, i want to upload file that must be (image or pdf) using cordova plugin.

```
<button id="userCertificate" style="color:black"  onclick="getFile(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">Choose File</button>

     function getFile(source) {     
     navigator.camera.getPicture(onFileURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
     destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
     sourceType: source });
      } 
      }


    function onFileURISuccess(URI) {
    alert("File URI = "+ URI);    
    }
```

URI - i am getting content URI only when i am **select an image** from gallery, but i want file URI to fetch filename and type.

Kindly help me to overcome this problem.
thanks in advance.